# Qual o erro nessa atividade em c

Tags: c

Preciso que os valores negativos inseridos pelo usuário não entrem no cálculo e, ainda, que esta inserção negativa seja cancelada pelo programa.

O enunciado diz o seguinte:

> A prefeitura de uma cidade fez uma pesquisa entre seus habitantes, coletando dados sobre salário das pessoas. A prefeitura deseja saber:
>
> - A média salarial da população.
> - O maior salário.
> - A quantidade de pessoas com salários acima de R$ 1.000,00
>
> O final da leitura dos dados acontecerá com a entrada de um salário negativo.

Parte do código que já fiz:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)

{
    
    int quant_sal=0,salario_1000=0,soma=0,maior=0;
    float salario=1;
    
    printf("Insira o salario: ");
    scanf("%f",&salario);
    
    maior=salario;
    
    while(salario>=1){

        soma=soma+salario;
        
        if(salario<=0){
            printf("Salario invalido");
        }
        
        if(salario>1000){
            salario_1000++;
        }

        if(salario>maior){
            maior=salario;
        }
        
        
        

        printf("Insira o salario: ");
        scanf("%f",&salario);

    }
        
    printf("A media de salario e: %.1f\n",soma/salario);
    printf("O maior salario e: %d\n",maior);
    printf("Salario acima de 1000 e: %d\n",salario_1000);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A média é igual a soma dividido pelo total de elementos. Você não está rastreando esse total na variável `quant_sal`, esse é o seu problema.

Além disso, há várias simplificações possíveis no seu código. Em especial, com uma mudança no `while`, só precisamos ler o salário uma vez e funciona mesmo se o primeiro salário entrado for negativo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int quant_sal = 0, salario_1000 = 0;
    float salario, soma = 0, maior = 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("Insira o salario: ");
        scanf("%f", &salario);

        if (salario < 0) break;

        soma += salario;
        if (salario > 1000) salario_1000++;
        if (salario > maior) maior = salario;
        quant_sal++;
    }

    printf("A media de salario e: %.1f.\n", quant_sal == 0 ? 0 : soma / quant_sal);
    printf("O maior salario e: %.1f.\n", maior);
    printf("Ha %d pessoas com salario acima de 1000.\n", salario_1000);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Observe que o valor digitado pelo usuário só será somado (`soma += salario;`), comparado com 1000 (`if (salario > 1000)`), comparado com o maior (`if (salario > maior)`) e contado como um salário (`quant_sal++;`) se não tiver sido negativo (`if (salario < 0) break;`).

Note que como `salario` é comparado com `maior` e somado no `soma`, temos que `soma` e `maior` devem ser do tipo `float`, e não `int`, uma vez que `salario` é `float`.

Há ainda um detalhe no `quant_sal == 0 ? 0 : soma / quant_sal`. O uso do operador ternário é para evitar a divisão por zero se o primeiro salário informado já for um número negativo.

Comment: Opa, deu certo! Apenas no (maior=0;), quando coloquei em float ele não fez o rastreamento, porém deixei em int e deu certo.
De qualquer forma, te agradeço pelo tempo dispensado para verificação do código. Acabou me ajudando e me ensinando algumas coisinhas que estava em dúvida.

Comment: @HuckBoy Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema, marque-a como aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela. Isso também marcará a sua pergunta como solucionada/resolvida. Caso ainda não esteja satisfeito e lhe restem dúvidas ou objeções, sinta-se livre para comentar.

Comment: rss, esqueci desse detalhe!!
Obrigado!